# Unable to update nspr package on CentOS 6.7

Tags: linux, centos, yum, nspr

I have issues with one of my packages on CentOS 6.7. I want to update `nspr` package, but I'm unable to do that. 
The error is:

`installing package nspr-4.10.8-2.el6_7.i686 needs 284KB on the / filesystem`

When I type `sudo yum update nspr` I got addtional message: `There are unfinished transactions remaining. You might consider running yum-complete-transaction first to finish them.` I tried to use this command, but it does not help.

Result of `df -h` is:

`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       59G  9.0G   50G  16% /
none            2.0G  4.0K  2.0G   1% /dev
none            2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm`

Server reboot does not help either.
Any ideas what might be going on or how to fix this issue? 
Thanks for all tips:)

Comment: It means partition is out of disk space.  try - yum clean all.
In general, you need to revise your disk usage configuration (partition for boot/home/  etc.)

Comment: Tried `yum clean all` command, but it did not help. I also found information that it might be lack of free space, but take a look on `df -h` result. It says that i have 50G available? Is it possible that it shows wrong results?

Comment: what about df -h /boot

Comment: `df -h /boot` says 
`Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/simfs       59G  8.6G   51G  15% /`

Comment: one more thing:
du -h --max-depth=1 /
lsof /
ls -lSr | more

Comment: Hmm, it did not show anything unusual. The problem is that I'm almost 100% sure, that disk space is not an issue, as they are no any huge files etc. I actually solved the problem differently, please see my answer

Comment: Indeed. but it is rather a workaround than solving of the issue. AFAIK, there might be a reched limit of inodes:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode

Answer (score 1):

OK, I actually manage to solve that weird issue.
First of all, all I googled about this issue gave me information, that there is something wrong with free disc space. I did not believe it, because I know what I got on my server, I also scanned it for huge files and calculated the space covered by files, so df -h result was OK. I had lot of free space available.

I fixed it by editing `/etc/yum.conf` file and adding `diskspacecheck=0`. After that, suddenly everything worked out fine. Package has been updated correctly. Then I cleared out yum warnings with `yum-complete-transaction` command.

All good now! Thanks for all help provided:)